# How to properly use a Cloned theme in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In a few words, we have this active theme called `themename` located in this folder :

`/public_html/wp-content/ .. /themename-wp`

At this point, I am interested to install and use the same theme (the default settings version) but not updating, over the existing folder which contain some modifications in so many different places inside the files.

Reading different resources about this procedure, I am not so sure if renaming the new copied theme file (being inactive in this phase) from `themename-wp` in `newthemename-wp` will maintain the new installed theme 100% functional;

I have this concern because, If we need to replace the theme folder name into the theme files too, we have a situation:

-I've searched for `themename-wp` name with Agent Ransack all the theme files and I've found only 2 `.json` files containing this text. 
On the other hand,

-Searching for `themename` without `-wp`, which is the displayed name of the theme, there are about 60 files (`.css`, `.js` and mostly `.php`'s) that contain this text.

The question is: 

-Should I find and replace the theme name only where appears as `themename-wp` OR I need to make these changes in other files as well replacing `themename` with `newthemename` OR will be enough to rename the new copied theme file in `newthemename` and that's all?

Thank you,

Comment: Don't clone the theme, but rather set up a "Child" theme. Here's more information from the Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: The child theme is out of discussion in this case, the wp-template is too complex to be framed into a child theme :) I've been there, done that ... Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, in that case you don't need to change any of your cloned theme's internal file names or references, just the name of the theme in style.css

Comment: I'll try that, and I'll be back with a feed-back; thanks.